# Memory usage for lazy datatypes

Tags: haskell, memory, vector, lazy-evaluation

I've written a program that analyzes and performs operations on data from a file. My first implementation uses `Data.ByteString` to read the contents of the file. This contents is then converted to a Vector of samples, using `Data.Vector.Unboxed`. I then perform the processing and analyzation on this (unboxed) vector of sample values.

Just as an experiment, I wanted to know what would happen if I make use Haskell's laziness. I decided to do this simple test by using `Data.ByteString.Lazy` instead of `Data.ByteString` and `Data.Vector` instead of `Data.Vector.Unboxed`. I expected to see an improvement in memory usage. Even if my program eventually requires to know the value of every sample, I would still expect memory usage to rise incrementally. When I profiled my program, the results surprised me.

My original version finishes in about 20ms and its memory usage looks like this:
[image]
This looks like lazy behavior to me. Samples seem to be loaded into memory as they are needed by my program.

Using `Data.Vector` and `Data.ByteString` gave the following result:
[image]
This looks like the opposite of lazy behavior. All the samples seem to be loaded into memory at once and then removed one  by one.

I suspected this had something to do with my misunderstanding of `Boxed` and `Unboxed` types, so I tried using `Data.ByteString.Lazy` with `Data.Vector.Unboxed'. This was the result:
[image]
I have no idea how to explain what I'm seeing here.

Could anyone explain the results I'm getting?

**EDIT**
I'm reading from the file using `hGet`, this give me a `Data.ByteString.Lazy`. I convert this ByteString to a `Data.Vector` of Floats via the following function:

```
toVector :: ByteString -> Vector Float
toVector bs =  U.generate (BS.length bs `div` 3) $ \i ->
     myToFloat [BS.index bs (3*i), BS.index bs (3*i+1), BS.index bs (3*i+2)]
  where
    myToFloat :: [Word8] -> Float
    myToFloat words = ...
```

The floats are represented in 3 bytes.

The rest of the processing mostly consists applying higher-order functions (e.g. `filter`, `map`, etc.) to the data.

**EDIT2**
My parser contains a function that reads all the data from a file and returns this data in a vector of samples (using the previous `toVector` function). I've written two versions of this program, one with `Data.ByteString` and one with `Data.ByteString.Lazy`. I've used these two versions to perform a simple test:

```
main = do
  [file] <- getArgs
  samples <- getSamplesFromFile file
  let slice = V.slice 0 100000 samples
  let filtered = V.filter (>0) slice
  print filtered
```

The strict version gives me the following memory usage: 
[image]
The lazy version gives me the following memory usage:
[image]
This result seems to be the complete opposite of what I would be expecting. Could someone explain this? What is wrong with `Data.ByteString.Lazy`?

Comment: Are you linking the source here?

Comment: @Michael I'm sorry, I want to, but I'm not allowed to share the source. Is there any extra information I could provide you without sharing the source?

Comment: @ThomasVanhelden You could prepare a minimal demonstration of the issue that only involves the `ByteString`/`Vector` generation and consumption patterns, rather than your domain-specific code.

Comment: I'd be looking for lingering references to the lazy bytestring which could prevent it from being garbage collected while data is still being read. E.g. if you scan the string twice, then laziness won't help much. It's hard to tell without looking at the actual code.

Comment: @duplode I've added the `ByteString` to `Vector` conversion.

Comment: Since you are storing floats, there is no reason at all to use `Data.Vector` which is a pretty delicate type, since it just holds pointers to Haskell values, which may be thunks, rather than just holding the values themselves. There is almost no reason to use `Data.Vector` when you have a type like `Float` that can be unboxed.

Comment: @Michael That's why I tried using `Data.Vector.Unboxed` but the result is still weird and I can't explain it.

Comment: If you are building an intermediate vector of any sort, along the lines of `toVector`, then the fact that you are using lazy bytestring will be basically irrelevant, since the vector is a comparably sized structure and you are simply not streaming and lazy bytestring was not really helping.

Comment: I can't tell you how radically true it is that this cannot be solved without an exact minimal source, and all ghc hp2hs flags etc. that can reproduce the problem.   Apart from that we are speculating on which of about 17 variables is mattering.

Comment: @Michael That doesn't answer why the lazy bytestring requires that much more memory than the strict version. It also doesn't answer why the strict version seems to be acting lazy. Because it only seems to be loading values into memory as it needs them.

Comment: @Michael I've added a small example that reproduces the behavior in my second edit. I'm generating the report using `+RTS -hy`, I'm converting to ps using `hp2ps -e8in -c`, I'm converting to pdf using `ps2pdf`. My only ghc-options are `rtsopts` and `prof`.

Comment: Yes, it seems so but that is not what is going on, clearly. We need two programs where altering `import qualified Data.ByteString as B` to `import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B` makes the change - and the ghc flags

Comment: The business is in `getSamplesFromFile` and perhaps `myToFloat`. Note that `print` = `putStrLn . show`, so apart from nice laziness you are producing a gigantic linked list at the end. It's probably irrelevant, but what happens if you `print . sum` instead. Does it work with `myToFloat = toIntegral . sum`

Comment: Oh you are not using optimization? -O or -O2

Comment: If I run this the four ways, the only noticable difference is boxed/unboxed, this is because instead of storing floats the vector stores pointers, and the pointers point to floats or float-thunks. http://sprunge.us/PeIJ

Comment: @Michael Using `print . sum` makes a huge difference. The memory usage seems to be constant (in `+RTS -s`) and the `+RTS -hy` graph is empty (0 bytes x seconds).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data we have so far are not adequate to reproduce the problem. Here I run four versions of http://sprunge.us/PeIJ changing strict to lazy and boxed to unboxed. I am compiling with `ghc -O2 -rtsopts -prof` The only difference worth remarking on it that each real (pointer) element in the vector or stream in the `Data.Vector` version is pointing outside itself to a nice boxed Haskell float which takes up a pile of space. Everything is basically the same throughout, except the `Data.Vector` programs, as expected, have a big heap of blue at the top for these carefully packaged floats.

[image]

Edit 
Here is what I get if I just use `ghc -prof -rtsopts`

[image]

Comment: This is totally different from what happens on my system. I've ran your code with your compile flags and my results are still the same as those I've provided in my question. Just switching from `Data.ByteString` to `Data.ByteString.Lazy` in your code, makes it take up a lot more memory (exactly is as in my 2nd edit).

Comment: Are you using -O2 which is standard for `vector` programs? (The whole library is compiled with -O2)

Comment: Yes I'm using -O2. In fact, I'm using the same ghc-options as you are.

Comment: I can get results sort of like yours if I omit optimization, see above

Comment: Again, the salient difference is unboxed v. boxed.

Comment: Adding/removing the optimization doesn't seem to have any effect on my result. Maybe this has something to do with my machine?

Comment: I think you can see in the boxed strict case that the red is the unanalyzed thunks the vector is pointing to since they decline as the blue, for Float, increases. Its obscure, for sure.

Comment: Are you using -fforce-recomp or equivalent between compilations? The compiler might just be saying 'I already did that one' when you switch to -O2

Comment: No, I don't. I always make a minor change to the comments in the source to ensure recompilation. Compiling with -fforce-recomp didn't make a difference.

Comment: I am using `The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.0.1` and `vector-0.11.0.0`

Comment: I'm using the same exact versions. This is really weird.

Comment: here's a hacked together repo https://github.com/michaelt/troubles i made a sandbox with vector then `sh all.sh` I just left ps files since on os x I can do `open noopt/*` and view them as pdfs together.

Comment: I've messed around a lot and I cannot reproduce the behavior using your code. It turns out that I can only reproduce the behavior when I'm using a cabal project. I create a new folder and initiate the project using `cabal init`. If I then paste your code into `Main.hs` and compile using `cabal install`, the strange behavior occurs. This even happens when I compile manually inside the `cabal` project using `ghc -O2 -rtsopts -prof`. If I manually compile outside of the `cabal`project, I don't get the behavior. So it seems to have something to do with `cabal`.

Comment: I've added this information to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330183/evaluation-of-higher-order-functions

Answer (score 4):

You are using `length` on a lazy bytestring. That will demand the whole string. If that was the only use of the input lazy bytestring, garbage collection could make it work in constant space. However, you access the string after that for further computation, forcing the whole data to persist in memory.

The solution to this would be avoid `length` altogether, and trying to fold over the lazy bytestring (just once!) so that streaming can do its job.

You can for instance do something like

```
myread :: ByteString -> [Float]
myread bs = case splitAt 3 bs of
   ([x1,x2,x3], end) -> myToFloat x1 x2 x3 : myread end
   -- TODO handle shorter data as well

toVector bs = U.fromList $ myread bs
```

Probably there's a better way leveraging `Vector` stuff. `U.unfoldr` looks promising.

Comment: The lazy bytestring will all be in memory, but can it take up so much more space than the corresponding strict bytestring?  I was guessing that there may be an additional problem if the `Data.Vector` vector is just pointing to a zillion thunks of the form  `myToFloat [BS.index bs (3*i), BS.index bs (3*i+1), BS.index bs (3*i+2)]`. The size of such things would add up, I think.

Comment: @Michael AFAICS, it should not take much more memory more than the strict variant. Thunks should be evaluated when you insert them in the _unboxed_ vector (unlike the boxed). Do you really need the bytestring after you built your vector? If you are not using it anymore, it should be possible to make it work in a streaming fashion, consuming only O(1) memory. (The vector will still use O(n), of course)

Comment: my (totally halfbaked) idea was that the decline in memory use in the second picture was from the successive reduction of the thunks to floats of the things the (boxed) vector was pointing to.

Comment: @Michael Ah, I missed the part where you said you moved to boxed vectors as well. That will keep those thunks around, yes.

Comment: If `length` forces the whole bytestring to be in memory, why is this not the case when I use the strict variant? When I use `data.ByteString`, the program seems to require memory incrementally. It looks like the behavior I would expect from a lazy implementation. Even though I also use `length`. But then, when I switch to `Data.ByteString.Lazy`, I suddenly demands the whole string? So how can you explain this 'reversed' behavior?

Comment: @ThomasVanhelden I was wondering about that as well, but I have no clear idea. I wonder if there's some optimization which kicks in for strict BS but does not for lazy ones, but that seems weird. Using lazy BS should not increase memory wrt strict too much.

Comment: @chi For `Data.ByteString.Lazy.length` seems to force the whole bytestring to be in memory. This is not the case for `Data.ByteString.Length`. I've solved this by the metadata of the file instead of `length`.

Comment: @chi The real problem seems to be with my processing of the data. The lazy bytestring gets rid of data it doesn't need anymore. E.g.: mapping over the vector will only load into memory the chunk of the current value. When the mapping moves to a value in the next chunk, it is loaded into memory and the previous one is dropped. When I then apply another higher-order function to the vector, the dropped data has to be loaded into memory again. I think this is what causes the memory problems.

Comment: @ThomasVanhelden Strict length does not force the bytestring because a strict bytestring is already completely in memory. A lazy one should not discard data and re-fetch it later. What if it was user input? There's no way to re-fetch that. A lazy bytestring either keeps data in memory or lets it be garbage collected when no longer needed (provided optimization/fusion did its job).

Comment: @chi I don't think the strict bytestring is already in memory. I request the samples from my file, then use `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Slice` to request 1000 samples and print them to a file. I see that only approximately the size of 1000 samples ever was in memory during the execution of the program. I may be wrong about the re-fetching, but why does the lazy bytestring require that much more memory then?

Comment: @chi Every test I do gets me more confused. I've added more information in my question.

Comment: Note that the indexing going on inside `generate` would mean that in the end the whole lazy bytestring would need to be in memory even if you didn't apply length. `bs` is referred to repeatedly and it is lazily developed as it is indexed further along, and nothing can be released until `generate` is done.