# Evaluation of higher-order functions

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I've written a function `getSamplesFromFile` that takes a file and returns its contents as a `Vector` of `Floats`. The functions reads the contents of the file into a `Data.ByteString` using `Data.ByteString.hGet`, it then converts this `Data.ByteString` to a `Vector` of `Floats` using:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.Word
import System.Environment
import GHC.Int
toVector :: BS.ByteString -> V.Vector Float
toVector bs =  vgenerate (fromIntegral (BS.length bs `div` 3)) $ \i ->
     myToFloat [BS.index bs (3*i), BS.index bs (3*i+1), BS.index bs (3*i+2)]
  where
    myToFloat :: [Word8] -> Float
    myToFloat = sum . map fromIntegral 

vgenerate n f = V.generate n (f . fromIntegral)
```

I was testing how lazy this program was via a small test program:

```
main = do
    [file] <- getArgs
    samples <- getSamplesFromFile file
    let slice = V.slice 0 50000 samples
    print slice
```

If I run this on a 13MB file, it seems as if every sample is loaded into memory, even though I only need 50000 samples to be printed. 
[image]
If I make a small modification to this problem and first map or filter over it, the result is different:

```
main = do
    [file] <- getArgs
    samples <- getSamplesFromFile file
    let slice = V.slice 0 50000 samples
    let mapped = V.map id slice
    print mapped
```

This way, it seems that not every sample was loaded into memory, only the slice:
[image]
To make sure this was the case, I ran the program again with a slice of half the size (25000 samples):
[image]
Now, the memory usage seems to be proportional to the size of the slice. Just because I map over the slice with `id`.

The result is the same when filtering over the samples. How can applying a higher-order function suddenly make the behavior lazy?

**EDIT**
The problem seems to have to do something with `cabal`. As you can see from the pictures, I was testing my code inside a `cabal` project called *laziness*. I can't reproduce this weird behavior if use a separate `Main.hs` file outside of a cabal project. This is the `Main.hs` I'm using:

```
module Main where

import qualified Data.ByteString     as BS
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import           Data.Word
import           GHC.Int
import           System.Environment
main = do
    [file] <- getArgs
    samples <- getSamplesFromFile file
    let slice = V.slice 0 50000 samples
    --let filtered = V.filter (>0) slice
    let mapped = V.map id slice
    print slice

getSamplesFromFile = fmap toVector . BS.readFile

toVector :: BS.ByteString -> V.Vector Float
toVector bs =  vgenerate (fromIntegral (BS.length bs `div` 3)) $ \i ->
     myToFloat [BS.index bs (3*i), BS.index bs (3*i+1), BS.index bs (3*i+2)]
  where
    myToFloat :: [Word8] -> Float
    myToFloat = sum . map fromIntegral

vgenerate n f = V.generate n (f . fromIntegral)
```

I don't experience the weird behavior if I do the following:

1. Create a new directory somewhere via `mkdir`
2. Add the above `Main.hs` to the directory.
3. Compile using `ghc Main.hs -O2 -rtsopts -prof`.
4. Run via `./Main myfile.wav +RTS -hy`.
5. Create the pdf using `hp2ps` and `ps2pdf`.

I do experience the weird behavior if I do the following:

1. Create a new directory, *laziness*, via `mkdir laziness`.
2. Initiate a `cabal` project via `cabal init`.
3. Add the above `Main.hs` to `/src`.
4. Add `ghc-options: -O2 -rtsopts -prof` to `laziness.cabal`.
5. Compile using `cabal install`
6. Run via `laziness myfile.wav +RTS -hy`.
7. Create the pdf using `hp2ps` and `ps2pdf`.

I even experience the weird behavior if I:

1. `cd laziness/src`
2. Compile using `ghc Main.hs -O2 -rtsopts -prof`.
3. Run via `./Main myfile.wav +RTS -hy`.
4. Create the pdf using `hp2ps` and `ps2pdf`.

So it seems that this behavior only occurs when the code is inside a `cabal` project. This seems weird to me. Could this have something to do with the setup of my `cabal` project?.

Comment: `myToFloat` doesn't work. And __please__ include your `import`s.

Comment: @Zeta I'm sorry. I fixed it and added imports.

Comment: Ah. _Lazy_ bytestrings. Allright. Still a typo, by the way ( `vgenerate` should be `V.generate`). That being said, `map id` forces the slice. And while it sounds strange, forcing in this case is actually more memory-friendly if the size of your original vector is a lot greater than the slice.

Comment: @Zeta I'm so sorry. It shouldn't be a lazy bytestring. I've made so many versions of this as a test so I added the wrong version. What you're saying about forcing the slice seems right though.

Comment: I haven't checked all of `vector`'s code yet, but a `slice` is basically a pair of "offset" and "new length", which still use the original `Array a` pointer. So if you use the slice, the original Array must be populated, since it's strict and unboxed, probably in order to use `show`. However. if you use `force`, you copy the memory, which can be taken into account when you actually generate your "new" vector. You could compare the resulting core. In the non-force version, it evaluates all elements, whereas in the force-version, it evaluates just the first 5000.

Comment: Now that I had some time to compile it: I cannot reproduce this behaviour. Please add your `getSamplesFromFile`, as well as the used compiler version.